# navgationdrawer и viewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-navigation-drawer

подскажите пожалуйста. сделал двойную навигацию navgationdrawer и viewPager. Навигация по одним и тем же фрагментам, не могу соединить. Нужно сделать так чтобы при выборе пункта меню переходило на соответствующий таб и выводился нужный фрагмент и тоже самое с viewPager. щас при пролистывании табов меняются фрагменты и получается что фрагмент измененный в viewPager накладывается на фрагмент выбранный в navgationdrawer

код MainActivity

```java
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Home"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Gallery"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Slideshow"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tools"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        final ViewPager viewPager =(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        TabsAdapter tabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabsAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

код адаптера TabsAdapter

```java
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import com.example.navigation.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment;
import com.example.navigation.ui.home.HomeFragment;
import com.example.navigation.ui.slideshow.SlideshowFragment;

/**
 * Created by tutlane on 19-12-2017.
 */

public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;
    public TabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NoofTabs){
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NoofTabs;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position){
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                HomeFragment home = new HomeFragment();
                return home;
            case 1:
                GalleryFragment gallery = new GalleryFragment();
                return gallery;
            case 2:
                SlideshowFragment slideshow = new SlideshowFragment();
                return slideshow;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вы именно хотите, но задача не из тривиальных и это факт. Я вижу два основных решения: писать свой контроллер на обработку данной задачи или использовать уже готовывый: https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/557-urok-24-android-navigation-component-vvedenie.html. Свой писать сложно но вы сделаете именно то что хотите, а вот использовать готовый... не факт что вы им сможете в полной мере решить свою задумку.

Comment: Мне нужно реализовать такую работу. пример у меня есть фрагмент под названием Home, есть таб с таким же названием и есть пункт меню в navgationdrawer с таким же названием. и при свайпе и при выборе пункта меню должно выпадать на этот фрагмент. нажал кнопку в navgationdrawer на пункте Home поменялся фрагмент соответствующий ему и переключился на вкладку Home. и так же с viewPager выбрал вкладку home вышел фрагмент home и в пункте меню стал выбран пункт соответствующий табу и фрагменту. Надеюсь понятно обьяснил

Comment: Да, вполне, коментарий что выше вам нужно делать именно так. Или можете просто создать CallBackHell. Хотя впринципе не такой уж Hell и получится)